# Making elements long enough to fit parent div box in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to layout a simple form but I'm not sure if doing it the right way.My first question is:
If I have the following html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        text text
    </div>

  <div class="span6">
       text text
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make smaller margin-left rule that is applied to span* class? I mean, the second div here will be 30px left from the first one, but what If I would want to make it only 10px, how to do that?

Second questions: If I have the following html

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <label>text2</label> 
             <select>
                  <option>5</option>
          </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

How do I make select button to take width space as long as the parent div is wide? I tried adding width:100% to the select and it works fine, but when paddings are added, select  is wider then the parent?

Answer (score 0):

If you give the select 100% then add padding then the width becomes 100% + padding.

You could make the width say 94% and add 3% padding so the total adds up to 100%.

```
select {
    width: 94%;
    padding: 3%;
}
```

If you add a border to the select element this will also be included in the width calculation so you'll have to adjust your values accordingly.

You could also consider looking at using CSS3 box sizing but I'm not 100% sure if it will work on selects:

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/